# Masters Theorem $T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{4}) + (\log(n))^2$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, computer-science

I have a problem that I am trying to understand using the master theorem since it applys.  The problem at hand is, $T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{4}) + (\log(n))^2$.   I am not sure I am correct in my final solution.  The $\log(n)^2$ is what is causing me some doubt.  I believe this recurrence relation satisfies case 1, see below.  Any guidance or correction would be greatly appreciated!  Here is my work:

1. $T(n) = 2T(n/4) + (\log(n))^2$
2. a = 2, b = 4, k = 0, p = 2
3. following, $\log_b a$ or $\log_4 2 = .5$
4. Since .5 > k = 0, we satisfy case 1
5. Thus it is: $\Theta(n^{\log_4 2})$

Is this correct, and if not, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 4 could use some more work. Namely, you need to show that $(\log(n))^{2} \in O(n^{c})$ for some $c < 1/2$. This shouldn't be too hard. For example, take $c = 1/3$. We have that:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\log(n))^{2}}{n^{1/3}} = 0.
\end{align*}

I'll leave it to you to fill in the details for the limit computation.

So $(\log(n))^{2} \in O(n^{1/3})$ (actually, $(\log(n))^{2} \in o(n^{1/3}))$.

Your reasoning is otherwise fine.

Comment: Is my answer correct though?  I am not sure what you mean by your reasoning.  What would $(\log (n)) ^2$ equal?

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, but you are missing details. In the setup for the Master Theorem, $f(n) = (\log(n))^{2}$. So you need to show that $f(n) \in O(n^{c})$ for some $c < 1/2$.

Comment: Also, one thing to add- for upper division math and CS courses, it usually isn't enough that you arrived at the correct conclusion. The (most) important aspects are that you fully understood and articulated your reasoning. I'm being a little picky about the details for that reason. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your time, I appreciate your guidance!  I will work on what I am missing, however, I am also happy I arrived at the correct answer too.